# Using a Spinner to Change webView

Tags: android, webview, onclick, spinner

I have an app that sends a user input to a website's search URL, like so:

[image: App]

To do this, I was wondering:

1. How do I store the last webpage visited on each site to cache?
2. How should I add the website names to the spinner?
3. How would I write the code for a spinner item's click event?

Essentially, the process of the app is:

1. Enter search query
2. Select site from spinner to load query into
3. If the same site is selected again, the page should not reload

e.g. User searches "phone" and selects Website 1. Website 1 is now loaded. Website 2 is selected and loaded. Website 1 is reselected, but does not reload.

Comment: Could post what you have done so far and what's not working?

Comment: @issathink That's the problem. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you need to know to get started with WebView : [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

There's all you need (according to your description) :

- The canGoBack() method returns true if there is actually web page history for the user to visit.
- canGoForward() to check whether there is a forward history. If you don't perform this check, then once the user reaches the end of the history, goBack() or goForward() does nothing.
- etc.

For the Spinner you can check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/).

Comment: If I wanted to use tabs in the Action Bar instead of a spinner, would that be a similar process?

Comment: Sure definitely, there's no big difference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html